# Is this a valid PHP date equality check?

Tags: php, datetime

Is this a valid PHP date equality check?

```php
$zeroDate = date("0000-00-00 00:00:00");

if( date($someOtherDateString)==$zeroDate ) {
// . . . 
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? Does it work??? Do you know how [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) actually works?

Comment: Guys I appreciate the constructive introspection and research you are encouraging me to do, but this is a simple yes/no answer.  Provide a 'no' with why and I can give you 10 points.

Comment: My guess is the OP did try it and it probably did work just fine in a limited number of tests, but now he's simply asking the community if this is the right overall approach. If anything, I might change the question to "is this the best way to check for exact date quality" rather than just "valid", but it's a reasonable request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be more comfortable testing true date/time values than strings that just look like date times.

I have two basic approaches for testing date quality. The first one is: are the variables equal (like the track you're on above, but not string tests). The second one is: is there a non-zero delta between the dates?

Try this:

```
// convert strings to time
$zeroDate = strtotime("0000-00-00 00:00:00");
$someOtherDate = strtotime("0000-00-00T00:00:00-00:00");

// sanity check on the data
var_dump($zeroDate);
var_dump($someOtherDate);

// Approach #1
if ($someOtherDate === $zeroDate) {
    print "They are equal\n";
} else {
    print "They are not equal\n";
}

// Approach #2
if (($someOtherDate - $zeroDate) === 0) {
    print "They are still equal\n";
} else {
    print "There are not equal\n";
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

No.Use the Unix timestamp instead to get an integer:

```
$zeroDate = date('U', "0000-00-00 00:00:00");

if( date('U', $someOtherDateString)===$zeroDate ) {
// . . . 
}
```